# JavaScript new project with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2008, ide, new-project

How can I work with JS in Visual Studio 2008? In example if I have only 1 JS file which I want to work with. So what project type should I create in VS to add JS file to it so VS will see how it works? Maybe someone could write a short step-by-step guide how to do so? I would be grateful! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an ASP.NET Web Application, and put your JS in there. And remember, [Google is your friend](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=asp.net+tutorial+vs2008) :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! :) I have googled wrongly... only on js project in vs but nothing came good.. only about intellisens and etc.. :(